# How can i use scripts open SpriteEditor in unity4.6+

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

everyone,i want to use c# open spriteeditor window in unity4.6. if in else unity version open it can do this:`EditorApplication.ExecuteMenuItem("Window/Sprite Editor")`，but int 4.6+,this code  inivalid.

Comment: post the error message

Answer (score 0):

When using `EditorApplication`, make sure to have this on top of your script:

```
using UnityEditor;
```

However, it seems Unity's sprite editor is not part of the menu items...

[image: Window menu]

`ExecuteMenuItem` can only execute menu items that are also visible in Unity's menu. `"Window/Animator"` for example would be a valid string. Maybe the Sprite Editor has moved since 4.6+?

Comment: yes,in unity4.6+, the SpriteEditor not in window/...  . so i do not know use my script open SpriteEditor in unity4.6+. open it only in (texture)Sprite type click button of SpriteEditor

Comment: I don't think there is a way to programmatically start the Sprite Editor now... This is a great example why I don't recommend using `ExecuteMenuItem`, since Unity can easily break it with every release.

Comment: Thank you very much . i don't konw else way can open it(i want to use script ,haha..).